# Website that communicates with Server

Tags: database, client-side, procedures

I'm a newbie. Im thinking about developing a website that people can be come members of and login. I know that ill need to have a server with a database to store info. What i need to know is, do i just need to create the server host site host it and then have my website hosted somewhere else. To sum up, what's needed in the process of developing this type of site?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can host everything in the same server. Back-end and front-end are words just to describe the organization of your code, being HTML, CSS and Javascript files your front-end, and the rest your backend.

Most host services today have Ruby, PHP and ASP supported by all plans, just as MySQL. There are no need for developing two parts in your application - but you can do that if you want.

I suggest you start by studying what is the MVC structure.